# i want to display the number of student from the DB into a card

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bootstrap-5

Student Controller

```
@GetMapping("/numberStudent")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getStudentNumber(){
        String repot = null;
        repot = studentRepository.StudentsNBR();
        return repot;
    }
```

Studeent repository

```
@Query("select count(e) from Student ")
    public String StudentsNBR();
```

so basicly i want to display the number of the student in a card using bootstrap

```
<div class="col-sm">
                <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/557595531526799390/1033961333584052224/spring.gif"
                        style="height: 180px;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="p-1 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
                        <h5 class="card-title" align="center">Spring BOOT</h5></div>
                        <script>
                        jQuery(function($) {$.number( 1234.5678, 2 );
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "/numberStudent"});
                </script>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the problems you encountered.

Comment: i made the logic , when it come to displaying the result i have no idea . i even search on google but i didn't find something useful

Comment: how i can display the return of a method into a card in bootstrap .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to add model interface and create a variable that hold the return,

```
model.AddAttribute("var_name",var_name);
```

and go to the view and call it `[th:text=${"variable-name"}]`